# my flutter app not be run in android version 8 in real device

Tags: flutter, dart

** just completed my flutter app and I want to install him in different real devices, in devices with android version 10.0 is working perfectly but in devices with android version 8.0 not be installed**

Comment: Check and set minimum version in your gradle files. Thank you: android_project/android/app/build.gradle. Change the minSdkVersion to the desired

Comment: @Davis what's the version we be to change right now is 16

Comment: 16 is Android 4.1 perhaps it's your targetSdk. What's your target SDK?

Comment: @Davis  targetSdkVersion 30

Comment: It should work then! Just upgrade flutter. traced from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14625

Comment: Android 10 is already more than two years old. Is there any good reason to support even older versions?

Comment: worked with targetSdkVersion 30 and 16

Answer (score 0):

Go to
`Project>android>app>src>main>AndroidManifest.xml` and check for the parameter `targetSdkVersion`

Change that to `29`